# Designing Master/Detail in XCode,MVC

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, model-view-controller

I'm new to MVC and XCode and I'm having trouble translating my conceptual understanding of MVC to designing and implementing concrete classes. I'm hoping to get a little advice on how to structure the controllers and views to get the intended UI. This is for an OS X app (not iOS).

My object model is 3 objects: `Batch` which has some text members and an array of products. `Product` has some text members and an array of images. `Image` is basically a path to where the image is stored.

The idea is that the primary view will display a listing of all of the batches' thumbnails and titles. Clicking on one will clear the screen and displa the thumbnails for all of the products in that batch. Clicking on a product will clear the screen and open up the product details page which displays the product data and thumbnails of all of the images. Clicking on an image thumbnail displays the image taking up the full window.

The questions are struggling are along the lines of

- Which controllers do I use? Which do I inherit from?
- Do I use real controllers or `NSObject`s in the XIB objects list?
- Which views do I use? Which do I inherit from?
- Which views can be in the XIB and which have to be dynamically added?

Clearly, I am clueless and I'm not finding good tutorials that explain the "Why?".
Any direction is appreciated since my previous attempts are convoluted and almost certainly breaking conventions and standard practices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple actually provides quite a nice tutorial/sample on the exact sort of situation you're asking about: [Creating a Master-Detail Interface](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Tasks/masterdetail.html)

One thing worth bearing in mind is that Apple's concept of MVC is a little different from the "classic" MVC pattern (or I suspect Martin Fowler would say so, anyway). I suspect you'll have an easier time with it if you put your existing concept of MVC aside and work through some of the introductory examples provided by Apple.

At 30,000ft, Cocoa is arguably more like Model-View-Presenter, or the unfortunately named Model-View-ViewModel patterns. It's also good to remember that the overall pattern can be nested, or instantiated multiple times (i.e. turtles all the way down). In the simplest case of a document-based application, you'll have an NSDocument subclass. This will own the model, and will typically be responsible for mutating the model, as well as reading and writing it to disk. In this way, it's a classic-MVC controller. It will also, in the default Xcode templates, be the owner of the window, and therefore will do double duty as a "ViewController" which is a Cocoa-ism that is roughly equivalent to the "Presenter" in MVP. The views are typically specified in a XIB file, whose lifecycle is managed for you by the framework.

I'm going to stop now, because there are perfectly good references out there that will do a better job teaching you than I can do here. Check this out: [Document-Based App Programming Guide for Mac](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks. I skimmed the MAster/Detail article yesterday and thought it wasnt quite what I was looking for. I revisit it again today and hopefully I'll be familiar enough to adapt it by the time I'm done.